# Keep aspect ratio when using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a ggplot hexbin chart that I want to show with ggplotly. However, when I use the ggplotly function the aspect ratio, previously fixed for the gplot chart, is lost.

Minimal working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(11)
df<-data.frame(xvar=rnorm(1000,0,4),yvar=rnorm(1000))

#nicer colours
palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
colours<-palette(32)

p1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=xvar,y=yvar))+ coord_fixed(ratio=1)+
  stat_binhex(bins=50)+scale_fill_gradientn(colours=colours)
p1
ggplotly(p1)
```

I have approximated the ratio with the following code but the ratio is still slightly wrong because of the legend.

```
ratioaxes<-(max(df$yvar)-min(df$yvar))/(max(df$xvar)-min(df$xvar))
ggplotly(p1,height=ratioaxes*500,width=500)
```

Is there any way that I can preserve this ratio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is still quite some things in `ggplot2` that do not survive the transfer to `plotly`, see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/161) for an overview. For this issue see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/218).

Comment: I do understand that this functionality is not available. My approach is quite close to preserve the aspect ratio but I believe there is a small deviation due to the legend.

The aim of my question was to know if there is some way around.