# Keep x and y scales same (so square plot) in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I created a plot that has the same x and y limits, same scale for x and y ticks, hence guaranteeing the actual plot is perfectly square. Even with a legend included, the code below seems to keep the static plot (sp object) itself perfectly square even when the window in which it is positioned is rescaled:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(30))
y = abs(rnorm(30))
value = runif(30, 1, 30)
myData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, value=value)
cutList = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
purples <- brewer.pal(length(cutList)+1, "Purples")
myData$valueColor <- cut(myData$value, breaks=c(0, cutList, 30), labels=rev(purples))
sp <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=valueColor)) + geom_polygon(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(labels = as.character(c(0, cutList)), values = levels(myData$valueColor), name = "Value") + coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 2.5))
```

However, I am now attempting to transfer this static plot (sp) into an interactive plot (ip) through ggplotly() that can be used in a Shiny app. I notice now that the interactive plot (ip) is no longer square-shaped. The MWE to show this is below:

**ui.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 180,
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
    menuItem("Example plot", tabName="exPlot", selected=TRUE)
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "exPlot",
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
          box(width = NULL, plotlyOutput("exPlot"), collapsible = FALSE, background = "black", title = "Example plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE))))))

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title", titleWidth = 180),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(30))
y = abs(rnorm(30))
value = runif(30, 1, 30)

myData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, value=value)

cutList = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
purples <- brewer.pal(length(cutList)+1, "Purples")
myData$valueColor <- cut(myData$value, breaks=c(0, cutList, 30), labels=rev(purples))

# Static plot
sp <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=valueColor)) + geom_polygon(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(labels = as.character(c(0, cutList)), values = levels(myData$valueColor), name = "Value") + coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 2.5))

# Interactive plot
ip <- ggplotly(sp, height = 400)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  output$exPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ip
  })

})
```

It seems there may not be a built-in/clear solution at this time ([Keep aspect ratio when using ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767054/keep-aspect-ratio-when-using-ggplotly)). I have also read about a HTMLwidget.resize object that might help solve a problem like this (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/pull/223/files#r47425101), but I was unsuccessful determining how to apply such syntax to the current problem.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This helped me to fix the aspect ratio for a static plot in Shiny: http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2016/09/09/formatting-in-a-shiny-app/ 
I doubt that there is a similar solution for the interactive plot, because the information on plot width is missing in the session$clientData object.

Comment: Do your x and y-axis always have identical ranges?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I am sorry I did not specify that. No, they do not always have identical ranges.

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing with [fixed axis ratio](https://plot.ly/r/axes/undefined) to no avail.

Setting the plot margins to create a square plot worked for me.

[image]

The plot is kept square even when the axis range changes.

[image]

When the axis ratio should be identical (i.e. the units are square but the plot is not), one would need to adjust the code a little bit (answer will be updated soon).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(30))
y = abs(rnorm(30))
value = runif(30, 1, 30)
myData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, value=value)
cutList = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
purples <- brewer.pal(length(cutList)+1, "Purples")
myData$valueColor <- cut(myData$value, breaks=c(0, cutList, 30), labels=rev(purples))
sp <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=valueColor)) + geom_polygon(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(labels = as.character(c(0, cutList)), values = levels(myData$valueColor), name = "Value") + coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 2.5))
sp

#set the height and width of the plot (including legends, etc.)
height <- 500
width <- 500
ip <- ggplotly(sp, height = height, width = width)

#distance of legend
margin_layout <- 100
#minimal distance from the borders
margin_min <- 50

#calculate the available size for the plot itself
available_width <- width - margin_min - margin_layout
available_height <- height - 2 * margin_min

if (available_width > available_height) {
  available_width <- available_height
} else {
  available_height <- available_width
}
#adjust the plot margins
margin <- list(b=(height - available_height) / 2,
               t=(height - available_height) / 2,
               l=(width - available_width) / 2 - (margin_layout - margin_min),
               r=(width - available_width) / 2 + (margin_layout - margin_min))

ip <- layout(ip, margin=margin)
ip
```